# Loop infinito ao passar por endereços de memória

Tags: c

Estava fazendo esse código cujo objetivo é usar ponteiros para preencher um array com uma progressão aritmética. Porém, não consigo sair do primeiro loop.

```
int main() {

    int r, // Razão da PA
    i, // Contadora
    pa[10], // Array que será preenchido pela PA
    *ptrPA; // Ponteiro que vai apontar para o Array

    printf("Digite o primeiro termo da PA: \n");
    scanf("%d", &pa[0]);

    printf("Digite a razão da PA: \n");
    scanf("%d", &r);


    for (ptrPA = &pa[0] + 1; ptrPA <= &ptrPA[9]; ptrPA++) { // O ponteiro vai servir como contador
        *ptrPA = *(ptrPA - 1) + r; // Aplica-se a fórmula de PA para a posição do endereço que o ponteiro aponta
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", pa[i]); // Exibe os valores armazenados
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O que pode estar causando isso? Obrigado.

PS: Quando eu tento executar o programa ele encerra após eu entrar com os valores, e no debug do eclipse ele fica preso no primeiro loop

Comment: Existe algum motivo pra usar o ponteiro? Ele não parece ser necessário.

Comment: Realmente não é, é só para exercitar

Comment: Normalmente eu posso melhorar isso e resolver, o problema é que eu não sei se vou tirar alguma coisa que você colocou artificialmente. Quando há um requisito inventado, fica complicado dar uma resposta. Eu simplesmente tiraria o ponteiro, afinal não sei o que dá pra aprender usando algo desnecessário. Então eu sequer entendo a intenção disso `ptrPA = &pa[0] + 1; ptrPA <= &ptrPA[9];` mas certamente o erro está aí.

Comment: Eu estou atribuindo ao ponteiro o endereço de memória da posição '1' do array, pois a posição '0' já está sendo ocupada pelo primeiro elemento que eu havia pedido ao usuário. A condição para o loop rodar é eu ter um endereço de memória menor ou igual ao da última posição do array (nesse caso é a posição 9). O problema deve estar aí mesmo, eu não sei porque o loop não encerra depois da nona posição.

Comment: Com esse código eu estava tentando responder esse exercício:

http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/Operacoes-Matematicas-com-Ponteiros-em-C.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (ptrPA = &pa[0] + 1; ptrPA <= &ptrPA[9]; ptrPA++)
//                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

devia ser

```
for (ptrPA = &pa[0] + 1; ptrPA <= &pa[9]; ptrPA++)
//                                 ^^^^^
```

Comment: Nossa, não sei como deixei passar esse detalhe. Obrigado.

Comment: `&pa[0] + 1` == `&pa[1]` == `pa + 1`